# Can the API Key on a MobileConnect message be changed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect

Any insight would be helpful if this is possible through the UI or through an API call. The purpose of changing this is so that the API key is the same across business units (qa/prod environments) - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time the MobileConnect message is created, it's assigned an API identifier, and as far as I know, there is no way to change it.

You would need to assign some sort of variable for the key to switch between your environments.

Comment: OK - thanks for confirming. This is in line with what I'm finding.

Answer (score 1):

The API keys change hourly (clientID/Secret) are unique and linked to an account. More info on SE.  The MessageIDs are unique, static and cannot be changed.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not clear. I am speaking towards the external key (API key) for an outbound SMS message not the clientID/secret for the REST services.